Script variable conflicts with a named object (Gradle/Groovy DSL)
I am surprised to find out that the name spaces of script variables and named objects interact in a very bad way. In my real build script, the conflicting name was integrationTest and it looked like I can configure test or foobar, but not integrationTest.
Questions: Is there any way to add a named object whose name is the same as that of a script variable? Is there any way to mark an identifier as a name from the objects name space?
It looks like the very possibility of a conflict between DSL object names and script variable names just kills the idea of DSL.
A sort of remedy could be something like "Do not use variable names that may be used for named objects, this is bad style", but there is no such rule.
My project uses Gradle 6.2.1, but your comments about later versions are welcome.
The project is a Gradle plugin in Groovy generated with ../someotherproject/gradlew init in the directory booksplugin. To see how it works, run the test in BooksPluginFunctionalTest.groovy.
Originally the books plugin was an example from Gradle docs, to read more about how it works, read this: https://discuss.gradle.org/t/confusing-example/14278
BooksPlugin.groovy:
package booksplugin
import org.gradle.api.Project
import org.gradle.api.Plugin

public class BooksPlugin implements Plugin<Project> {
    public void apply(Project project) {
        def extension = project.extensions.create("booksplugin", BooksPluginExtension)
        def books = project.container(Book)
        books.all { // execute this for each added book, this is no iteration
            sourceFile = project.file("src/docs/$name")
        }
        project.tasks.register("listBooks") {
            books.each { book -> /* which "books" is being iterated? */
                println "$book.name -> $book.sourceFile"
            }
        }
        extension.extensions.books = books
    }
}

class BooksPluginExtension {
    boolean someFlag = true
}

class Book {
    final String name // a Book is a named domain object
    File sourceFile

    Book(String name) {
        this.name = name
    }
}

BooksPluginFunctionalTest.groovy (this is where the name conflict happens):
package booksplugin
import spock.lang.Specification
import org.gradle.testkit.runner.GradleRunner

class BooksPluginFunctionalTest extends Specification {
    def "can list books"() {
        given:
        def projectDir = new File("build/functionalTest")
        projectDir.deleteDir()
        projectDir.mkdirs()
        new File(projectDir, "settings.gradle") << ""
        //new File(projectDir, "build.gradle").delete()
        new File(projectDir, "build.gradle") << '''
            plugins {
                id('booksplugin.greeting')
            }

            // !!!!!!!!
            // define a test and a script variable
            // this variable causes and exception when its name conflicts with the name of a named object
            def greeting =
                            project.tasks.register("greeting") {
                doLast {
                    println("Hello")
                }
            }

            booksplugin {
                someFlag = false
            }
            booksplugin {
                books {
                    quickStart {
                        sourceFile = file('src/docs/quick-start')
                    }
                    userGuide {
                    }
                    developerGuide {
                    }

                    // !!!!!!!!
                    // conflicts with the variable name
                    // org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'functionalTest\'
                    // Caused by: org.gradle.internal.metaobject.AbstractDynamicObject$CustomMessageMissingMethodException: Could not find method call() for arguments ...
                    greeting {
                    }
                }
            }
        '''.stripIndent()

        when:
        def runner = GradleRunner.create()
        runner.forwardOutput()
        runner.withPluginClasspath()
        runner.withArguments("listBooks", "-s")
        runner.withProjectDir(projectDir)
        def result = runner.build()

        then:
        result.output.contains("src/docs/quick-start")
        result.output.contains("src/docs/developerGuide")
        result.output.contains("src/docs/userGuide")
        result.output.contains("src/docs/greeting")
    }
}

(If you comment out the line with def greeting =, the test will succeed.)
build.gradle (generated by gradlew init and probably edited a bit):
plugins {
    id 'java-gradle-plugin'
    id 'groovy'
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    testImplementation 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.3-groovy-2.5'
}

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        greeting {
            id = 'booksplugin.greeting'
            implementationClass = 'booksplugin.BooksPlugin'
        }
    }
}

// Add a source set for the functional test suite
sourceSets {
    functionalTest {
    }
}

gradlePlugin.testSourceSets(sourceSets.functionalTest)
configurations.functionalTestImplementation.extendsFrom(configurations.testImplementation)

// Add a task to run the functional tests
task functionalTest(type: Test) {
    testClassesDirs = sourceSets.functionalTest.output.classesDirs
    classpath = sourceSets.functionalTest.runtimeClasspath
}

check {
    // Run the functional tests as part of `check`
    dependsOn(tasks.functionalTest)
}

